# macOS App manually signing with provisioning profile for App Store got error Code signature invalid

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin.mac, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I try to use manual signing in macOS using provisioning profile. But everytime I try to run it will crash with error

> EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)

If I try to use automatically manage signing or manually manage signing but without provisioning profile it works fine. What is wrong with my provisioning profile? I need to use manual manage signing because my app actually is Xamarin.mac which is not possible in VS for Mac to sign automatically or sign manually without provisioning profile. I am not using weird entitlement. I only need app sandbox to release app store so in my provisioning profile I don't add any capabilities

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could post the commands you are executing.

Comment: Just a wild guess: I once had a code signing problem because my App bundle contained extended attributes (try `xattr -lr mybundle.app`). If there are extended attributes, remove them before code signing by executing `xattr -cr mybundle.app`.

Comment: I am actually don't know how to manually code sign. I use it all from IDE (VS for Mac/XCode). In XCode if I am using provisioning profile it will build the app but it will crash when I launch it with error `Code Signature Invalid`. I am trying it on newly created app.

Comment: You're using a macOS and Xamarin but are you developing an iOS app? or Android?

Comment: i am developing macOS app @Oren_C

Answer (score 2):

If your signature is invalid it is likely that you haven't created the correct type of certificate. There are several certificate types that can be instanced and your app will not build correctly if you have created the wrong certificate type.

Common certificate types include:

- iOS development
- iOS distribution
- Mac app development
- Mac app distribution
- Mac installer distribution
- Developer ID application
- Developer ID installer

For more information about manually creating your certificate, see my answer to this question: [macOS installer certificate evaluation error in Keychain: Invalid Extended Key Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286693/macos-installer-certificate-evaluation-error-in-keychain-invalid-extended-key-u/51407892#51407892)

Also note that during development you would use an iOS development certificate, but for uploading to the App Store via iTunes connect, you will need an iOS distribution certificate and it needs to be enabled on an Apple ID that has paid for iOS distribution. For more information on enrollment to the Apple developer program, which will enable you with privileges to get a valid distribution certificate see here: https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/

If you are sure that it is not a problem with the certificate itself, do note that there other parameters involved when creating a provisioning profile manually - it's not just a certificate + private key. This is a profile that needs to be created in the Apple developer portal, but as long as you have a valid Apple ID to use for creating the provisioning profile it shouldn't be difficult. There are detailed instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning but allow me to paraphrase:

1) Go to the Apple Developers Member Center (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action), and under the section Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles select "Provisioning Profiles".

2) Click the + button, in the top right corner to create a new profile.

3) From the Development section, select the radio button next to iOS App Development, and press Continue:

[image: Selecting provisioning profile type]

4) From the dropdown menu, select the App ID that to use

5) Select the Certificate(s) to include in the provisioning profile, and press Continue

6) Select all the devices that the app will be installed on, this will be all the devices and computers that belong to your Apple ID that will get a distribution certificate installed on it.

7) Provide the Provisioning Profile with an identifiable a name, and press Continue to create the profile

8) Press "Download" to download the provisioning profile onto a Mac

9) Double-click on the file to install the provisioning profile in Xcode. Note that Xcode might not show any visual clues that it has installed the profile except for opening. This can be verified by browsing to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts. Select your Apple ID and click "View Details..." Your new provisioning profile should be listed, as illustrated below:

[image: List of your provisioning profiles]

After the provisioning profile has been successfully created it may be necessary to restart Xcode so that all the development certificates are correctly loaded and available for use.

---

**Checklist:**

- Is my code signing certificate the correct type
- Was my provisioning profile properly registered in the Apple Developer portal (https://developer.apple.com) for the Apple ID that is used on the machine building the app
- Is my Apple ID correctly enrolled in the Apple Developer program with no outstanding fees to be paid, or licenses like EULA to accept.
- Have I downloaded my provisioning profile from my Apple Developer portal and correctly installed it on my machine that is trying to build / release the app.

NOTE:
In order to distribute apps to the app store there is no choice but to create and pay for the provisioning profile within the developer portal, and install it on your machine by downloading it from Apple.

Best of luck!

Comment: I am actually developing macOS app and right now I have no problem in developing iOS app